# iPhone 6s has a longer pre-main time than 6 plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, optimization, ios10.3

When I was trying to optimize the app's launch time, I found an interesting fact that the pre-main time needed on iPhone 6s is actually much longer than an iPhone 6 plus(warm launch).

On iPhone 6 plus, it looks like this:

```
Total pre-main time: 241.93 milliseconds (100.0%)
     dylib loading time:  74.81 milliseconds (30.9%)
    rebase/binding time:  15.96 milliseconds (6.6%)
        ObjC setup time:  23.67 milliseconds (9.7%)
       initializer time: 127.31 milliseconds (52.6%)
       slowest intializers :
         libSystem.B.dylib :   7.21 milliseconds (2.9%)
libBacktraceRecording.dylib :   5.97 milliseconds (2.4%)
                AirshipKit :   5.17 milliseconds (2.1%)
               My App : 199.60 milliseconds (82.5%)
```

However, on iPhone 6s, it tripled the time:

```
Total pre-main time: 891.80 milliseconds (100.0%)
     dylib loading time: 680.36 milliseconds (76.2%)
    rebase/binding time:  59.18 milliseconds (6.6%)
        ObjC setup time:  42.74 milliseconds (4.7%)
       initializer time: 109.43 milliseconds (12.2%)
       slowest intializers :
         libSystem.B.dylib :   7.36 milliseconds (0.8%)
               My App : 147.96 milliseconds (16.5%)
```

They both are running on the same system(iOS 10.3). I think iPhone 6s have a larger RAM & better CPU than the 6 plus. But I don't understand why it's actually takes longer time to finish the pre-main task.

Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks!

P.S: I did try several times.

Comment: Maybe stupid question, is the iPhone6 Plus a personal phone and the iPhone6 a test device?

Comment: The 6s is a personal phone and 6 Plus is a test device. Would this make some difference?

Comment: I think that is the reason. After I closed all the apps on the 6s and reboot and then opened the same app several times. The pre-main time dropped sharply! WoW...